# How to fix file system's CHS geometry?

Tags: filesystem, gparted, fsck

I'm trying to check FAT16 file system with GParted and the check fails with the following message:

> The file system's CHS geometry is (484, 16383, 63) is invalid. The partition table's CHS geometry is (31130, 255, 63). If you select Ignore, the file system's CHS geometry will be left unchanged. If you select Fix, the file system's geometry will be set to match the partition table's CHS geometry.

The check just fails without any Ignore/Fix prompting. How do I fix this?

Comment: Since I'm not sure this will help, I'm posting a comment instead of an answer: You might try dosfsck (aka fsck.vfat).

Comment: Thanks @soulsource, `dosfsck -lv` just shows that all files are checked and statistics. No info about geometry at all.

Comment: @eigenein are you using the latest version of GParted?

Comment: @devav2, I was using 0.11.* and after updating to 0.13.1 GParted has allowed me to choose Fix, then the error has gone away. Please, post the suggestion as an answer so I will able to accept it.

Comment: @eigenein Glad that you resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the latest version of GParted will fix the issue.

The older version seems to have some bugs.

[Source](http://osdir.com/ml/gnu.parted.devel/2006-06/msg00012.html)